# Points of continuity for a piecewise defined function.

Tags: analysis

Define the function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$  by

$$g(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2\text{ when }x \text{ is rational, }\\
-x^2\text{ when }x\text{ is irrational.}
\end{cases}$$
At what points is the function continuous?

So, intuitively, it looks like the only point of continuity would be at $0$ as $0$ would take on the same value in both cases? If I am correct in my thinking. I know that $0$ is rational, but I guess I just  don't fully comprehend why I think it is at $0$, but I would like to.

I am a bit confused on how to prove this with the sequential definition of continuity. I know I have to take a sequence in $x_n$ with a certain limit $x_0$, and then show that $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x_0)$.

If I take the sequence $\{x_n\}$ that converges to $0$, then I can show that the limit of $g(x_n)=(x_n)^2$ also converges to $0$ which is $g(0)$. My problem is with that previous line. Do I choose the first case of the piecewise function, or second case? Do I take the absolute value of $g(x)$ in general?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you get different limits if the sequence, $x_n$ takes values from only the rationals, from only the irrationals, or from some mix of rationals and irrationals?

Comment: I think I see it now. It would not change limits as I chose the limit to be 0 for that sequence. So, even if it would have irrationals, limit would still be 0. So, how would I put that in more "mathematical" terms? Am I then able to take the limit of absolute value of g(x)?

Answer (score 1):

To show that $g$ is discontinuous at $x_0$ whenever $x_0\neq 0$, choose sequences $x_n$ converging to $x_0$ that are either only rational or only irrational.

To show that $g$ is continuous at $0$, you take a sequence $x_n\to 0$ and want to show $g(x_n)\to 0$. Can you show that $|g(x_n)|\to 0$? Then you must also have $g(x_n)\to 0$.